# Задача по PHP или JS

Tags: javascript, php

Есть три цифры, если одна цифра равно суммы других двух чисел должно выводится True в противном случае False. если ли какое то легкое решение? можно и на js

```
$a = 1
$b = 2
$c = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если всего три числа, достаточно простого перебора вручную:

```js
function check(a, b, c) {
  if (a + b === c) return true;
  if (a + c === b) return true;
  if (b + c === a) return true;
  return false;
}

console.log(check(0, 1, 2));
console.log(check(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: `let check = (a, b, c) => a + b === c || a + c === b || b + с === a`   %)

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkNumber(a, b, c) {
  if (a + b === c) return true;
  else-if (a + c === b) return true;
  else-if (b + c === a) return true;
  return false;
}

console.log(check(0, 1, 2));
console.log(check(1, 2, 3));
```